# Colorbar and its range shared between two plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I adapted this code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73099652/2369957) that demonstrates how to share a colorbar and its range for two plots, but it doesn't seem to work when the range of the two plots are different - in the case of the posted code, the plots have the same range (half-open interval [0.0, 1.0)). I generated two plots with different ranges and the colorbar only follows the last plot. Is the code posted wrong for a general case? How do I make the colorbar have the range of the two plots?

Adapted code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211) 
im = ax1.imshow(np.random.uniform(low=0.00001, high=5, size=(100,100)))
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
im = ax2.imshow(np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.6, size=(100,100)))
plt.colorbar(im, ax=[ax1, ax2], aspect = 40)
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I generated two plots with different ranges and the colorbar only
> follows the last plot.

This is because `im` is overwritten when running `im = ax2.imshow(np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.6, size=(100,100)))`.

To have both images share the same colorbar, you need to combine both arrays and use the min and max values of the combined array in `imshow` as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183501/6440589):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

array_1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.00001, high=5, size=(100,100))
array_2 = np.random.uniform(low=0.3, high=0.6, size=(100,100))

combined_array = np.array([array_1,array_2])
_min, _max = np.amin(combined_array), np.amax(combined_array)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
ax1 = plt.subplot(211) 
im = ax1.imshow(array_1, vmin = _min, vmax = _max)
ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
im = ax2.imshow(array_2, vmin = _min, vmax = _max)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.00001, vmax=5)

fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, ),
             ax=[ax1, ax2], aspect = 40)

plt.show()
```

This returns the following image:

[image]